# Supervisord on Fedora configuration error

Tags: fedora, supervisord

I am trying to install supervisor on my Fedora 17, using this link as reference:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-manage-supervisor-on-ubuntu-and-debian-vps

It works fine except one trivial problem (I believe).

> A simple configuration for our script, saved at /etc/supervisor/conf.d/long_script.conf, would look like so (...)

My problem is, that I have only files/directories:

```
/etc/supervisord/
/etc/supervisord.conf
```

I have tried to create conf.d directory under /etc/supervisord/. I have put my config file into /etc/supervisord/conf.d/ and /etc/supervisord/ and also /etc/sueprvisor/.

Despite my effort when issuing command:

```
supervisortctl reread
```

I receive:

```
No config updates to processes
```

Anyone has a clue what I might be doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fedora 17? Why so old?

Comment: Driver/kernel compatibility issue, over my head for now, so I am stuck. :/